# Regex for a string including one expression and excluding another issues

Tags: r

So I have this list of URLs, but for some reason the regex expression I am using will not eliminate the last two URLs from the list.

```
"https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-7500-Watt-Gasoline- Powered-Electric-Start-Portable-Generator-and-25-ft-Extension-Cord-100219/206268632"                 
"https://www.homedepot.com/p/Reliance-Controls-40-ft-30-Amp-Generator-Power-Cord-PC3040/202216500"                                                                            
"https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-25-ft-120-Volt-Generator-Power-Cord-48034/203501795"
```

I want to eliminate any URL that contains "cord" and does not contain "and". So ultimately I want the expression to just return the first URL. I have other URLs in the full list that do not contain "cord" that I want to keep, so I can not just eliminate anything without "cord" and "and".

```
.[!grepl("(?!.*and)(?=.*[Cc]ord)", ., perl = T)]
```

This is what I have been trying, but it still returns all three URLs.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `^((?!and).)*Cord((?!and).)*$` I used does not contain and on both sides of cord since and might come before or after cord.

You can do:

```
a[!grepl("^((?!and).)*Cord((?!and).)*$",a,ignore.case = T,perl=T)]
[1] "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-7500-Watt-Gasoline-Powered-Electric-Start-Portable-Generator-and-25-ft-Extension-Cord-100219/206268632"
```

or:

```
grep("^((?!and).)*Cord((?!and).)*$",a,ignore.case = T,perl=T,invert = T,value = T)
[1] "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-7500-Watt-Gasoline-Powered-Electric-Start-Portable-Generator-and-25-ft-Extension-Cord-100219/206268632"
```

For faster manipulation, you can decide not to capture the group and thus use:

`^(?:(?!and).)*Cord(?:(?!and).)`

```
 a = rep(a,1000)
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    a=grepl("^((?!and).)*Cord((?!and).)",a,ignore.case = T,perl=T),
    b=grepl("^(?:(?!and).)*Cord(?:(?!and).)",a,ignore.case = T,perl=T)
  )
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    a 8.604448 8.631186 8.693752 8.656785 8.716235 9.077194   100   b
    b 7.915523 7.944821 7.999503 7.967861 7.998580 9.221692   100  a
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better, "single" regex expression to do it, but here is a solution in two parts

First, identify all that contain "cord"

```
a <- c("https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-7500-Watt-Gasoline-Powered-Electric-Start-Portable-Generator-and-25-ft-Extension-Cord-100219/206268632",
       "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Reliance-Controls-40-ft-30-Amp-Generator-Power-Cord-PC3040/202216500",                                                                           
       "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-25-ft-120-Volt-Generator-Power-Cord-48034/203501795")

library(stringr)

str_detect(a, regex('cord', ignore_case = T))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Then, identify all that contain "and"

```
str_detect(a, regex('and', ignore_case = T))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Then we subset your vector of URLs with the combination you need, in this case, not having "cord" without "and"

```
    a[str_detect(a, regex('cord', ignore_case = T)) &
           str_detect(a, regex('and', ignore_case = T))]
[1] "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-7500-Watt-Gasoline-Powered-Electric-Start-Portable-Generator-and-25-ft-Extension-Cord-100219/206268632"
```

Comment: This is a solution, but not for my case, because like I mentioned, the rest of the URL list has URLs that I want that do not contain "cord". So I want those URLs and all the ones that contain "cord" without "and". I could make two lists and combine them, but I am looking for a more clean method.

Comment: @MtnBee You simply need to negate the second part of the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I like to write my Regex the way my mind thinks. I've broken the problem into two cases.

Case 1: you have some digits, then "and", then possibly some digits, then "cord", then possibly some digits. 
Case 2: you have some digits, then "case", then possibly some digits, then "and", then possible some digits.

Put each of these cases in grouping parentheses and put an or between them `()|()`

Add some case sensitivity to the regex for "and" and "case". I just made the first character case insensitive, but you could do more if needed.

```
str_detect(a, "(.+[Cc]ord.*[Aa]nd.*)|(.+[Aa]nd.*[Cc]ord.*)")
```

An example and description of how it works:
[https://regexr.com/3snfq][1]

This all assumes you have a working link and must have something such as "http://" before your "and" or "cord".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a complex regex is the way to go here, it's more expensive in ressources, less readable, and not generalizable to more constraints.

Here is a base solution and an update on Onyambu's benchmark (also adding Felipe's solution that I corrected):

```
a[grepl("and",a) & grepl("cord",a,TRUE)]
# [1] "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Champion-Power-Equipment-7500-Watt-Gasoline-Powered-Electric-Start-Portable-Generator-and-25-ft-Extension-Cord-100219/206268632"

a = rep(a,1000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  # ad=str_detect(a, "(.+[Cc]ord.*[Aa]nd.*)|(.+[Aa]nd.*[Cc]ord.*)"), # too slow
  o1 = a[!grepl("^((?!and).)*Cord((?!and).)",a,ignore.case = T,perl=T)],
  o2 = a[!grepl("^(?:(?!and).)*Cord(?:(?!and).)",a,ignore.case = T,perl=T)],
  fe = a[!str_detect(a, regex('cord', ignore_case = T)) |
           str_detect(a, regex('and', ignore_case = T))],
  mm = a[grepl("and",a,perl = T) | !grepl("[Cc]ord",a,TRUE, perl=T)],
  unit = "relative"
)
# Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    o1 5.789945 5.735891 5.591111 5.767107 5.620815 5.863636   100
#    o2 5.338966 5.302216 5.187022 5.318472 5.210676 5.422635   100
#    fe 2.609088 2.777571 2.753290 2.838782 2.815973 2.664935   100
#    mm 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```